# How to find file that placed a line in my header

Tags: themes

I am having a line of code in my header that I can't seem to find where it is coming from, checked both files and database, am sure am missing something, are you guys aware of any methods to find for pieces of code where they are called from ?

Kind regards,
Cristian

Comment: give us a little more details on what the line is please.

Comment: Search your entire installation for 'send_header'. You can also try changing theme and turning plugins on and off to see if / when it goes away. Is it one that WordPress generates by default, e.g. canonical page links and links to the REST API, or something a plugin might generate e.g. Strict-Transport-Security, or something else altogether?

Comment: @mrben522 https://sadaghian.com/ line in header: <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>

The website was created maybe 3-4 years ago, GA was put on it, but I guess the plugin has been removed and somehow this is still called, I need to remove it in order to start with Google Tag Manager. I've checked the entire website and in Database, what I found I deleted, yet it still appears in my header.

Comment: Oh you meant the HTML `<head>` - I thought you meant HTTP headers. But the advice about changing theme and plugins stands. If this script tag isn't in your theme then it'll be a plugin hooking wp_head and writing it; you could try removing the `wp_head()` call from your theme to see if that removes the script tag, else you'll have to search through everything that hooks wp_head to see which one is doing it.

Comment: If you are familiar with using the command line, you can try finding the file using `grep`: `grep -rn 'www.google-analytics.com'` will return the files and lines containing the string "www.google-analytics.com"

Comment: I did and it only shows up in a .wpress file, I removed it as best as I could from the website and db.

Answer (score 0):

Install the String Locator WordPress plugin (free):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/

You can then search through all the files on your server, looking for `google-analytics.com` and do some inspection on the files found to see if any of those are the culprit.  Chances are it's hard coded in your theme header files, or there's a plugin that's enqueuing the script.

You can also use a DB search and replace plugin, just set config to do a "dry run" to search for `google-analytics.com` to see if it's saved in the db anywhere:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

I would also recommend that you try using a different browser as well to check this, to make sure some Chrome (or whatever browser you're using), that an extension is not injecting that on the page.

Comment: Thank you, I actually already use the string locator and Ari Adminer, I removed everything other then some files in a .wpress file. Also am not always on the browser so why would GA still be tracking that code.

Comment: Wasn't sure, was just trying to think of all possible reasons for that being added.  You could also try searching for just `analytics.js` to see if that turns up anything (in case they are dynamically somehow adding the URL (which would be very weird).  Who are you hosting your website with?

Comment: You can also try using this tool enter your website domain, and see if you can figure out who is the owner of the analytics ID that's being used http://www.domainmetrics.de

Comment: Or follow these instructions to figure out the analytics ID being used https://www.monsterinsights.com/docs/how-to-check-your-site-for-your-google-analytics-tracking-code/